# What is the Mathematical formula for sparse categorical cross entropy loss?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence, classification

Can anyone help me with the Mathematics of sparse categorical cross entropy loss function? I have searched for the derivation, explanation (Mathematical) but couldn't find any
I know it is not the right place to ask question like this. But I am helpless.

Comment: please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 1):

It is just cross entropy loss. The "sparse" refers to the representation it is expecting for efficiency reasons. E.g. [in keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/SparseCategoricalCrossentropy) it is expected that label provided is an **integer** `i*`, an index for which target[i*] = 1.

```
CE(target, pred) = -1/n SUM_k [ SUM_i target_ki log pred_ki ]
```

and since we have sparse target, we have

```
sparse-CE(int_target, pred) = -1/n SUM_k [ log pred_k{int_target_k} ]
```

So instead of summing over label dimension we just index, since we know all remaining ones are 0s either way.

And overall as long as targets are exactly one class we have:

```
CE(target, pred) = CE(onehot(int_target), pred) = sparse-CE(int_target, pred)
```

The only reason for this distinction is efficiency. For regular classification with ~10-100 classes it does not really matter, but imagine word-level language models where we have thousands of classes.